# VBA for Excel to insert rows based on text in sequential rows

Tags: excel, vba

I receive an Excel report showing number of patients in a center based on the payer type. Column A lists the center name and the payer types. If there are no patients for a particular payer type, that payer is not listed in the list. I would like to run a script to insert a row as a placeholder wherever a payer is not listed. For example, this is the output of the report:

```
   A       |    B     |     C
           |          |
Region A   | Date1    | Date2
           |          |
Center 123 |          |
           |          |
Private    | 4        | 6
Medicaid   | 60       | 58
Total      | 64       | 64
           |          |
Center 456 |          | 
           |          |
Private    | 4        | 4
Medicare   | 6        | 8
Hospice    | 2        | 2
Managed Cr | 8        | 10
Total      | 20       | 24
```

But I need for all payers/total lines to be listed for each center:

```
Center 123

Private
Medicare
Medicaid
Medicaid Pnd
Veterans
Hospice
Assisted Lv
Managed Cr
Unassigned
Total
Bed Hold
Total with Bed Holds
```

Can this be done with VBA to, for example, insert a row after "Private" if "Medicare" is not in the next row - and then put "Medicare" in that new row (column A)? Then insert a row after "Medicare" if "Medicaid" is not in the next row - and put "Medicaid" in the new row, and so on down the list. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick question. Your title is vbscript, but your tag is excel-vba. No sure if you know they are two different things.

If your looking for a vba solution, also referred to as a macro, here's an idea.

If you are doing this for esthetics, turn the used range into a table, and hide the rows that don't have any values. This can be done without a macro. But here's a quick macro example:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim objTable As ListObject
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "<>"
End Sub
```

If you were looking for a vbscript solution, its similar, but different syntax.

And a note, you can "Record Macros" in excel. This will allow you to perform a task manually, and excel will give you the macro version of the action. It's not perfect, but for stuff like this it will give you a good place to start.

Comment: I changed the title to VBA - thank you and sorry for the error - obviously I'm new to vba.

Comment: I don't want to hide the rows that have no values - that is already the problem with the Excel report I receive. I want to insert rows so that the data for all centers (and there are over 50) all have the same number of rows. I copy and paste this data into another spreadsheet that is formatted with a specific number of rows per center.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can easily be done with VBA. These are the logical steps you need to take:

Go through each row; 
for each row; 
Check text in column A and text in the cell below; 
if no action is required, do nothing and go to the next row; 
if an action is required, execute the desired action;

You can update your question with the code you have so far and describe in detail where exactly you are stuck, and I am pretty sure that we will be able to help you. Please google a specific question first before you ask it here.